# Whiling uploading the multiple images getting the folder name in the database

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I am uploading multiple images but I am getting an issue. I am getting the folder name in the URL instead of the new image name. I am expecting the output `888539185.jpg, 1644594769.png`. How can I resolve this issue?

**Multiple slider logic**

```
$gallery_images = $_FILES['slider'];
$file_post = $_FILES['slider'];
if($file_post['name'][0]!=''){
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
         $location='assets/images/uploads/sliders/';
        if(!$r_value =resizeImage($file_ary[$i], $location, 800)){
            $status = 0;
        }else{
            $gallery_images[] = $r_value;
        }

    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($gallery_images);
$allsliders = implode(",",$gallery_images);
```

I uploaded only two images and `$allsliders` output

```
[slider] => Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,assets/images/uploads/sliders/888539185.jpg,assets/images/uploads/sliders/1644594769.png
```

I am expecting the slider output like this `[slider] =>888539185.jpg, 1644594769.png`

`$gallery_images` output

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 871430578.jpg
            [1] => download1.png
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/png
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /opt/lampp/temp/php0Giji9
            [1] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpNC4udL
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 344471
            [1] => 2806
        )

    [0] => assets/images/uploads/sliders/888539185.jpg
    [1] => assets/images/uploads/sliders/1644594769.png
)
```

**Image resize code here**

```
function imageResize($imageSrc,$imageWidth,$imageHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight) {

    $newImageWidth =$newWidth;
    $newImageHeight =$newHeight;

    $newImageLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    
    imageAlphaBlending($newImageLayer, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($newImageLayer, true);
   // $color = imagecolorallocate($newImageLayer$newImageLayer, 255, 255, 255);

    // fill entire image
    //imagefill($newImageLayer, 0, 0, $color);
    
    imagecopyresampled($newImageLayer,$imageSrc,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);

    return $newImageLayer;
}
function resizeImage($file, $path, $width){
  if($file['name'] != ""){
      $uploadedFile = $file['tmp_name']; 
      $sourceProperties = getimagesize($uploadedFile);

      //$newFileName = time().$file['name'];


      $filename  = basename($file['name']);
      $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $new1        = mt_rand();// random number 
      $new       = $new1.'.'.$extension;

      $dirPath = $path;
      $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];
     
      
      $height = number_format(($sourceProperties[1] / $sourceProperties[0]) * $width, 0, ',', '');
     
      switch ($imageType) {


          case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
              $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedFile); 
              $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1], $width, $height);
              $new_one = imagepng($tmp,$dirPath. $new);
              break;           

          case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
              $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedFile); 
              $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1], $width, $height);
              $new_one = imagejpeg($tmp,$dirPath. $new);
              break;

          case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
              $imageSrc = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedFile); 
              $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1], $width, $height);
              $new_one = imagegif($tmp,$dirPath. $new);
              break;

          default:
              echo "Invalid Image type.";
              exit;
              break;
      }


      if($new_one == 1){
          return $dirPath. $new;
      }else{
          return 0;
      }
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the variable name

```
if(!$r_value =resizeImage($file_ary[$i], $location, 800)){
            $status = 0;
        }else{
            $result_gallery_images[] = $r_value;
        }
```

Before changing need to set as empty array

```
$result_gallery_images= []
```

Before add for loop.

```
$gallery_images = $_FILES['slider'];
$file_post = $_FILES['slider'];
$result_gallery_images= [];
if($file_post['name'][0]!=''){
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
         $location='assets/images/uploads/sliders/';
        if(!$r_value =resizeImage($file_ary[$i], $location, 800)){
            $status = 0;
        }else{
            $result_gallery_images[] = $r_value;
        }

    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_gallery_images);
$allsliders = implode(",",$result_gallery_images);
```